# Why does my modal window open and close automatically?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, drupal-8

I created a search block that opens with a Modal link.

My site is on Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

The problem is that when the modal is displayed, it closes automatically. Why ?

Here is the code of my block :

```
<div{{ attributes }}>

<div class="modal-search-link">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-search">
    <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-search" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Lancer une recherche</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Here is my code JS, to close the menu at the opening of the modal :

```
  $('#block-formulaireexposerecherchepage-1').on('click', function () {
       $('#navbar-collapse-first').collapse('hide');
  });
```

You have to click on the menu at the top left and on the magnifying glass to open the modal window with the search block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you hide this div navbar-collapse-first that is the parent of the modal you open, so modal hides also with its parent

take this part of code of modal out of div navbar-collapse-first

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-search" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Lancer une recherche</h4>
         </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          {{ content }}
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```